# Get entry route

Tags: plugin-development, routing

I'm trying to create a dynamic rerouter based on [reroute plugin](https://github.com/davist11/craft-reroute), but with the improvement to automatically create a reroute when a new entry is saved. So I listen for the `entries.onSaveEntry` event, but how can I find its route ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an entry’s URI via `$entry->uri`.

If you want to be able to tell if an entry’s URI is actually changing, you will also need to listen to the `onBeforeSafeEntry` event, and store its original URI:

```php
private $_oldUris;

public function init()
{
    craft()->on('entries.beforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event) {
        /** @var EntryModel $entry */
        $entry = $event->params['entry'];

        // Store the entry's old URI
        if ($entry->id)
        {
            $this->_oldUris[$entry->id] = $entry->uri;
        }
    });

    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
        /** @var EntryModel $entry */
        $entry = $event->params['entry'];

        // Did the URI just change?
        if (isset($this->_oldUris[$entry->id]) && $this->_oldUris[$entry->id] != $entry->uri)
        {
            // Yes it did. The new URI is available at $entry->uri.
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```